# Struct layout shown incorrectly in MS Visual Studio Quick-Watch window

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a structure definition that looked like this:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int first;
    int second;
};
```

I have recently updated it, adding more members:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int first;
    int additional1;
    int additional2;
    int second;
};
```

I am debugging code that looks like this:

```
mystruct object;
...
object.second = 128;
printf("%d\n", object.second);
```

After executing the code, i look at `object.second` in the Quick-Watch window and see 0; however, the code outputs `128`. When i look at `object`, i see only `first` and `second` members, as if the Quick-Watch window still used my old structure declaration.

In addition, the address of `object.second`, if i print it from the code, is different from what i see in the Quick-Watch window if i enter `&object.second` there (off by a few words; my structure actually contains dozens of members, which i omitted for brevity).

I tried to fix these incompatibilities by recompiling, rebooting, reverting the recent change (i use a version control system) and returning it. What else can i try to fix this problem?

I use MS Visual Studio 2005. My code is actually C++ but this part belongs to the C/C++ common subset.

Comment: Have you tried to delete PDB and/or NCB files?

Comment: Didn't help (thanks for the idea though)

Comment: You say the code is in a common subset - have you rebuilt that (I assume it's a library)? Are you using anything to like [custom data type displays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf0e8s14.aspx)?

Comment: @tinman Yes, i tried to rebuild that; no, i don't use custom data type displays; all my types are just structs/integers anyway

Answer (score 1):

When you write `mystruct object;` it works on Visual Studio 2005 but the proper way to write it when you use normal struct decleration and not using a typedef needs to be `struct mystruct object;` as explained [here](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/CStructs.htm).

I'm not sure if that is the thing that bugged you, but give it a try.